# Parse json using ObjectMapper where json key contains json as a value

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I have a class with such structure:

```
class SomeClass {

        private String stringValue; 
        private Collection<String> collectionValue = new ArrayList<>();
        private String jsonStringValue;
        private boolean booleanValue;
}
```

And then I use

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
```

to parse this object from JSON.

The main problem is that jsonStringValue is a json inside of json:

```
{"stringValue" : "someString",
 "collectionValue" : ["123456", "234567", "hello"],
 "jsonStringValue" : "{
    "someKey" : 1,
    "anotherKey" : {
      "againKey" : "value"
     }
  },
  "booleanValue" : true
}
```

And trying to parse jsonStringValue it throws

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
```

Exactly "a" character from my example (json modified on security purposes)

I believe there should be some escaping rule for parsing json as a String.

How do I parse json value as a string?

Comment: You must escape quote characters in a string

Comment: @MauricePerry is it possible to avoid escaping quote characters? Because this feature is going to be used by a lot of users and it is not convenient to force them to escape quotes every time

Comment: No. It wouldn't be a valid string, and consequently, the whole thing wouldn't be valid json.

Comment: But the quotes are not from the users, are they? They are part of the json syntax like in `"someKey"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your JSON string is not **valid** because there is a redundant double quote before the left bracket in `jsonStringValue`. The valid one looks like this:

```
{
  "stringValue" : "someString",
  "collectionValue" : ["123456", "234567", "hello"],
  "jsonStringValue" : {
    "someKey" : 1,
    "anotherKey" : {
      "againKey" : "value"
    }
  },
  "booleanValue" : true
}
```

Second, `jsonStringValue` is not a simple `String` object, it is a nested JSON objects. Therefore, you are supposed to create corresponding classes for it as follows:

```
Class SomeClass {
    private String stringValue; 
    private List<String> collectionValue = new ArrayList<>();
    private JsonStringValue jsonStringValue;
    private boolean booleanValue;

    //general getters and setters
}

Class JsonStringValue  {
    private int someKey;
    private AnotherKey anotherKey;

    //general getters and setters
}

Class AnotherKey {
    private String againKey;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

At last, the given JSON string can be transformed into `SomeClass` POJO with `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeClass someClass = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, SomeClass.class);
System.out.println(someClass.getjsonStringValue().getAnotherKey().getAgainKey());
```

Console output:

> value

**UPDATED**

If you still want to transform the `jsonStringValue` object into `String`, an alternative way is shown as follows:

Create 2 classes - `SomeClassOriginal` and `SomeClass`, the only difference between them is the data type of `jsonStringValue`. The former one is `JsonNode` and later one is `String`.

```
Class SomeClassOriginal {
    private String stringValue; 
    private List<String> collectionValue = new ArrayList<>();
    private JsonNode jsonStringValue;
    private boolean booleanValue;

    //general getters and setters
}

Class SomeClass {
    private String stringValue; 
    private List<String> collectionValue = new ArrayList<>();
    private String jsonStringValue;
    private boolean booleanValue;

    public SomeClass(SomeClassOriginal someClassOriginal) {
        super();
        this.stringValue = someClassOriginal.stringValue;
        this.collectionValue = someClassOriginal.collectionValue ;
        this.jsonStringValue= someClassOriginal.jsonStringValue.toString();
        this.booleanValue= someClassOriginal.booleanValue;
    }

    //general getters and setters
}
```

Then you can get the `jsonStringValue` as `String` like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeClassOriginal someClassOriginal = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, SomeClassOriginal.class);
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(SomeClassOriginal);
System.out.println(someClass.getjsonStringValue());
```

Console output:

> {"someKey":1,"anotherKey":{"againKey":"value"}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I need to parse nested JSON object like a plain String because it can have various structure which is not need to be parsed on my side because it is handled by 3rd party library.

Comment: @Oleksandr Riznyk Hi, I have updated the answer, please check!